# Java split complex string with regex

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have a following string:

```
field 'data' OR field2 'data2 complex' AND (field3 'data3' OR field3 'data4')
```

I nedd to split it into a form:

```
[field,
data,
OR,
field2,
data2 complex,
AND,
(,
field3,
data3,
OR
field3,
data4,
)]
```

Is it possible to do it using regex? Please, help me to write correct one to solve that task. Thanks a lot

Comment: you aren't doing anything but splitting on spaces...?

Comment: can you explain more? what is the original string and what do you expect to divide it by?

Comment: @sweaver2112 No,its not splitting on space

Comment: This `regex` seems to capture :- https://regex101.com/r/zA5fC4/2

can't say about `split` though

Answer (score 1):

You could also use this regex:

```
    String[] list = s.split("'|(\\b(?![^']*?\\w'))");
```

The output is:

> [field,  , data,  , OR,  , field2,  , data2 complex,  , AND,  (, field3,  , data3,  , OR,  , field3,  , data4, )]

The idea to to split at word boundries (`\\b`) only if the next `'` is an opening apostrophe, not a closing one (because then you would be inside).

I've tried to clean up the empty spaces without messing up the regex, and I couldn't find a way (I'm new to regex). So please be welcome to edit it if you can.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your requirements correctly, you want *"single quote delimited sequences" OR parentheticals OR alphanumeric words*.

Thus you could [use this regex](https://regex101.com/r/dZ1lC3/1) (set global to true so you can tokenize it one at a time):

```
/('[^']*?'|\w+|[\(\)])/g
```

*[note: this simple regex would not account for nested or escaped single quotes in the string, to do this properly is possible with regex but much more complicated.]*

if you wanted to a single match and then access your match groups to get your data, [just account for the space delimiters](https://regex101.com/r/dZ1lC3/2):

```
/(?:('[^']*?'|\w+|[\(\)])\s*)+/
```